# How to extract single value from single line tuples?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, csv, database

I have a dump file of a database in the following form

```
('value1','value2',value3','value4'),('value1','value2',value3','value4'),...
```

I want first to have each tuple in a single line and next i would like to export only a single value (i.e:value3 from each tuple)

Comment: You want to be sure that none of the tuples are split by lines, (...).  Awk allows you to redefine the record separator, which here could be ),(  rather than \n or \r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting each tuple on a separate line:

```
sed 's@)\s*,\s*(@)\n(@g' your_file
```

To apply modifications to the file (instead of printing the modified file to stdout):

```
sed -i 's@)\s*,\s*(@)\n(@g' your_file
```

To report only `value3` (assuming a modified file):

```
awk -F',' '{print $3}' <your_new_file
```

This assumes the values themselves don't contain `,`. See Michael's comment below.

To do it all in one go (without modifying the file):

```
sed 's@)\s*,\s*(@)\n(@g' your_file | awk -F',' '{print $3}'
```

To simplify the above `awk` call, I made use of the fact that, given your example, we can split the input on `,` and `value3` will be the 3rd value and have no parens in it. If you had wanted `value1` or `value4` instead, you can do something like:

```
sed 's@)\s*,\s*(@)\n(@g' your_file | awk -F',' '{print $1}' | sed 's/[()]//'
```

This of course assumes your values don't have parens in their content.

Comment: Note that a naïve solution like the above breaks if the values themselves contain commas. Even so, +1 because you beat me to it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Good point. Added to answer.

Comment: i can't understand the meaning of symbol @ at sed

Comment: @curious `sed` uses whatever character you put after the `s` as a pattern separator (see [this](http://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/)). In this case I used `@` instead of `/` because I happen to think it's more readable. It's especially helpful if your pattern contains `/` (e.g. in path names).